# Cannot get listener and talker working on two machines

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, talker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have two machines #1 and #2.
I selected #1 as the master by

```
$ ssh #1
$ roscore
```

Now I opened a new terminal on #1 and then

```
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://#1:11311
$ rosrun test1 listener
```

(Now the terminal is halting, waiting for messages to be posted on the topic)

Now I go on machine #2 and

```
$ ssh #2
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://#1:11311
$ rosrun test2 talker
```

(The "Helloworld x" pops up continuously with incrementing x)

When I look at #1, the listener is still halting, I should expect "heard x" with incrementing x. If I try the two nodes on each machine, they work perfectly fine. It is just when I now use two machines.

Btw, they are in the same wireless network and I already check the network setup as in the ROS tutorial.

Could anyone solve my problem? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64606/cannot-get-listener-and-talker-working-on-two-machines/) by [Bholms](https://answers.ros.org/users/5097/bholms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2013-06-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeneralSpoonFul](https://answers.ros.org/users/8371/generalspoonful/) on 2013-11-02**:
I have the same problem and setting the ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME did not do it for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most probably you forgot to specify `ROS_IP` **or** `ROS_HOSTNAME` environment variables to make it work. From [the manual](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME):

> With the exception of 'localhost', it
> does not affect the actual bound
> address as ROS components bind to all
> available network interfaces. If the
> value is set to localhost, the ROS
> component will bind only to the
> loopback interface. This will prevent
> remote components from being able to
> talk to your local component.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0